# jQuery selector based on not having class inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to select an element based on what is not inside it's element.

```
<div class="person">
  <div class="name">Jason</div>
</div>

<div class="person">
</div>
```

What do I need to do to select the second `div` with the `person` class. I know there are `has` and `not` properties, do I need to combine them in some way to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use as selector:

```
$(".person:not(:has(.name))")
```

But i'd suggest you to filter it instead:

> Because :has() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :has() cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method.

```
$(".person").filter(function(){
    return !$(this).find(".name").length;
})
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about the inefficiency of `:has`. I guess that jQuery does something much like the `.filter()` solution internally so the two solutions are, in all probability, pretty similar.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Ya this is basically what is doing `:has()` but there was some bugs regarding this pseudo selector, however fixed on jq >1.8.2.

Comment: Ouch, that means it must have been buggy for some years from v 1.1.4 to v1.8.1

Comment: There's also the fact that jQuery selectors are often confused with CSS selectors - the question was mistitled and mistagged, which I have now fixed, but some of the downvotes could have come from this misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest jquery solution `$('.person:empty')`, but second div must be without space

```
<div class="person">
  <div class="name">Jason</div>
</div>

<div class="person"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for something like this,

```
function getPersonWithNoNameField() {
  $('.person').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('div.name').length === 0) {
      var ele = $(this);
      console.log(ele.html());
      return ele;
    }
  });
}

getPersonWithNoNameField();

For your need, you can customise the function to return element which you want.
```